# Creating a group of vertical buttons - Ionic

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass

I want something similar to this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMGyg.jpg

I do not want a side menu - since my views don't require side menu. I've tried using ionic col view layout but it creates a mess - I want the button group to take 100% height of the window and not slide other content to the right. Please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood everything right, you want `position: fixed;` on your div that contains all the icons. Try these styles on that div:

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
```

Comment: Thank you for replying:
I did the following as per your instruction. 
I got this result
http://imgur.com/a/OAdty

I'm attaching my code - for your reference.
View Code - http://pastebin.com/jFcVd0dw
CSS - http://pastebin.com/YNmfz9Eg

Kindly help.

Comment: If .left_band is the main container of your left sidebar, you should add these css properties to that div.

Comment: Also place your sidebar div outside of your grid

Comment: The issue I'm facing is that - if I make height 100%, the last item (exit button) goes to bottom of scroll view. I want this whole div to be fixed while only right layout to be scrolled. Is it possible? If I set ion-content scroll="false" it becomes so for entire view. Please help me.

Comment: Don't make height 100%. Make it position: fixed; top: 0; bottom: 0;

Comment: Can I have a jsfiddle/codepen with your code, working example if possible.

Comment: Actually, I'm working in a team. They don't allow me full access. Please, if possible, can you guide me on some chat? I won't consume much of your time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125945/discussion-between-kirobo-and-radu-dasclu).